# How do I fix my bootstrap Navbar spacing? I can't figure out how to expand it the full width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5, spacing

I am trying to create a website with a navigation bar that is the full width of the screen and has a black background. I want the links to also be centered and evenly distributed.

I want to get rid of the white space on the left and right and make it a full black background from end to end. I can't find any fixes.

CSS

```
.masthead {
    height: 25vh;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/BtbjCFUvBXs/1920x1080');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

/* NAVBAR */
  /* Evenly Distribute Navbar Components */
  .navbar-nav > li{
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
  }
  .navbar {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
```

HTML

```
<body">
<section class="header">
  <div class="container">
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="navbar2 col-md-12" data-interval="false">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MAD</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
        data-mdb-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book a Service</a>
          </li>
          <li class=[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKM0z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKM0z.png)"nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Shop</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: It would be better of you made a runnable code snippet from you HTML and CSS code. So, users can easily try testing the code within the post instead of running themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing here is due to the `container` as its limiting your nav to a certain with.

this can be resolved by moving your `container` element from the parent of nav to the child of nav, something like this.

```html
<section class="header">
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="navbar2 col-md-12" data-interval="false">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MAD</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
          data-mdb-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book a Service</a>
            </li>
            <li class=[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKM0z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKM0z.png)"nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                >Shop</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

or if you don't need to container you can either remove it or change the `container` class to `container-fluid` depending on your situation.

Comment: Hello, I tried both ways and I thought adding the container would help. Is the photo I posted showing up on your end? When I add a color to the background there is about two inches of white space on each side. The header extends past the color of the navigation bar.

Comment: Hi, I guess the image is missing from your question.

Comment: I actually resolved it by removing the container all together! Thanks for your help.